# Sort Proxy Array of Objects, localeCompare is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuejs3, arrayobject

Trying to use ES6 `arrayObj.sort(a,b) => a.property.localeCompare(b.property)` syntax but getting error:

> TypeError: a.property.localeCompare is not a function.

I'm thinking `localeCompare` is not in scope but do not understand how to bind it to the scope of sort, perhaps because the data is stored in a proxy?  I'm also working within VueJS 3 but don't think that is relevant to this issue.

```
myData = 
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(5)
0: {itemIndex: 1, itemFmt: 2, itemFmtName: 'Call To Order', guid: 'd66af412-00a0-4c49-b8b5-abaefb79fed0', maxCt: 1, …}
1: {itemIndex: 2, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: '9f7b9d34-3fcb-42c7-866e-a56f71a8aa4f', maxCt: 0, …}
2: {itemIndex: 4, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: '406bea5e-1cb0-4d90-96e9-9b80b64ff8ba', maxCt: 0, …}
3: {itemIndex: 5, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: 'ad9aacda-5100-4eef-9ead-c61e1ec0c285', maxCt: 0, …}
4: {itemIndex: 7, itemFmt: 3, itemFmtName: 'Roll Call', guid: '1715f7a3-066d-4787-8233-a36df2a729a9', maxCt: 1, …}

myData.sort((a, b) => a.itemIndex.localeCompare(b.itemIndex))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`localeCompare` is a [method of `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), but `a.itemIndex` is a `Number`, so the method would not be available on that property.

To sort by `itemIndex`, use subtraction on the two `Number`s:

```js
const myData = [
  {itemIndex: 1, itemFmt: 2, itemFmtName: 'Call To Order', guid: 'd66af412-00a0-4c49-b8b5-abaefb79fed0', maxCt: 1 },
  {itemIndex: 2, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: '9f7b9d34-3fcb-42c7-866e-a56f71a8aa4f', maxCt: 0},
  {itemIndex: 4, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: '406bea5e-1cb0-4d90-96e9-9b80b64ff8ba', maxCt: 0},
  {itemIndex: 5, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: 'ad9aacda-5100-4eef-9ead-c61e1ec0c285', maxCt: 0},
  {itemIndex: 7, itemFmt: 3, itemFmtName: 'Roll Call', guid: '1715f7a3-066d-4787-8233-a36df2a729a9', maxCt: 1},
]

// sort by itemIndex in ascending order
myData.sort((a,b) => a.itemIndex - b.itemIndex)

console.log(myData)
```

To sort by `itemFmtName`, use `localeCompare` on the two `String`s:

```js
const myData = [
  {itemIndex: 1, itemFmt: 2, itemFmtName: 'Call To Order', guid: 'd66af412-00a0-4c49-b8b5-abaefb79fed0', maxCt: 1 },
  {itemIndex: 2, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: '9f7b9d34-3fcb-42c7-866e-a56f71a8aa4f', maxCt: 0},
  {itemIndex: 4, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: '406bea5e-1cb0-4d90-96e9-9b80b64ff8ba', maxCt: 0},
  {itemIndex: 5, itemFmt: 6, itemFmtName: 'Title/Discussion/Motion', guid: 'ad9aacda-5100-4eef-9ead-c61e1ec0c285', maxCt: 0},
  {itemIndex: 7, itemFmt: 3, itemFmtName: 'Roll Call', guid: '1715f7a3-066d-4787-8233-a36df2a729a9', maxCt: 1},
]

// sort by itemFmtName in alphabetical order
myData.sort((a,b) => a.itemFmtName.localeCompare(b.itemFmtName))

console.log(myData)
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, [localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) works with strings.

Here is a helper function that checks whether the sort attribute is a string or a number.

```js
const data = [
  { index: 4, value: 'c' },
  { index: 2, value: 'a' },
  { index: 3, value: 'b' },
  { index: 1, value: 'd' },
]

const sortHelper = (data, sortBy) => {
  if (data.find(x => typeof x[sortBy] !== 'number')) 
    // sort by localeCompare
    return data.sort((a,b) => a[sortBy].localeCompare(b[sortBy]))
  else
    // sort by number
    return data.sort((a,b) => a[sortBy] - b[sortBy])
}

console.log(sortHelper(data, 'index'));
console.log(sortHelper(data, 'value'));
```